# Looking up a particular user in a particular group in AD using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been looking online for ways of doing this and I'm at a loss here.  I'm looking for a way to look up a particular user within a particular group in AD through powershell.  Here's what I've tried.

```
(Get-ADUser userName –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
```

I get a bunch of groups

```
(Get-ADGroupMember "groupname").name
I get a bunch of usernames
```

I tried this command but it's taking forever to get results.

```
(Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'username'})
```

Is there a way where I can get a command that both fast and efficient.  I'm also looking for their email address and surname and last name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: surname IS lastname.. BTW, better not use the `Name` property, but if you have it use the `SamAccountName` or `DistinguishedName` of the user you seek.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it is best not use the `Name` property, but if you have it use the `SamAccountName` or `DistinguishedName` of the user you seek to rule out ambiguous names.

```
$user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'GroupName' | 
        Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' -and $_.SamAccountName -eq 'userSamAccountName' } |
        Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, GivenName, Surname  # add more properties if you need them

# display the user object on screen
$user
```

Or do this way:

```
$user = $null
$member = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'TheGroupName' | 
          Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' -and $_.SamAccountName -eq 'TheuserSamAccountName' }

if ($member) { 
    # add more properties if you need them
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $member.DistinguishedName -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, GivenName, Surname
}
else {
    Write-Host "User 'TheuserSamAccountName' is not a member of group 'TheGroupName'"
}

# display the user object on screen
$user
```

The resulting `$user` object will also contain these properties:

`DistinguishedName`, `Enabled`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `SamAccountName`, `SID`, `UserPrincipalName`

If you don't need all of these properties simply filter them out using

```
$user | Select-Object DisplayName, EmailAddress, GivenName, Surname
```

Comment: I put in the command below It just goes back to the prompt.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

$user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'groupname' | 
        Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'username' -and $_.SamAccountName -eq 'username' } |
        Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, GivenName, Surname

Comment: sorry, let me re-edit the command.  Not sure why I'm not getting results with this command either.

$user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'groupname' | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq 'username' } | Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, GivenName, Surname

Comment: @paul I have edited the answer and put in alternative code. That part now tests the result of Get-ADGroupMember first and only follows up with Get-ADUser is a member is returned. P.S. The output of both code blocks is captured in the `$user` object. You need to display that object, otherwise the console won't show anything..